# Ошибка авторизации через аккаунты организации

Tags: asp.net, azure

Здравствуйте!
Возникла проблема, причину которой никак не могу понять. При создании приложения Asp.net можно выбрать тип авторизации "Аккаунты организации". Настроил это дело, все работало хорошо, все заходили без проблем. Недавно случилась странная вещь: половина людей заходит как обычно без проблем, а половина получает ошибку "Получен неправильный запрос", причем до сайта то дело не дошло, спросил логин - и сразу ошибка. В чем нужно искать ошибку? Дело в Азурной директории? Адфс? Может в самом приложении что не так? Как хотя бы понять закономерность, кого пускает, а кого нет?

Comment: Уж слишком мало информации по вопросу, что бы помочь...

Comment: @WalterNuss уже вроде начали разбираться, дело в том, что приложение получает неправильный токен авторизации. А вот почему так происходит - пока не разобрались